# Convert panda column to a string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to run the below script to add to columns to the left of a file; however it keeps giving me

```
valueError: header must be integer or list of integers
```

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

read_file = pd.read_csv("/home/ex.csv",header='true')

df=pd.DataFrame(read_file)

def add_col(x):
    df.insert(loc=0, column='Creation_DT', value=pd.to_datetime('today'))
    df.insert(loc=1, column='Creation_By', value="Sean")
    df.to_parquet("/home/sample.parquet")
add_col(df)
```

Any ways to make the creation_dt column a string?

Comment: have you tried option `header=0`  in `pd.read_csv`  ?

Answer (score 0):

According to pandas docs `header` is row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the data and must be int or list of int. So you have to pass `header=0` to `read_csv` method.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Also, pandas automatically creates dataframe from read file, you don't need to do it additionally. Use just

```
df = pd.read_csv("/home/ex.csv", header=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

read_file = pd.read_csv("/home/ex.csv")

df=pd.DataFrame(read_file)

def add_col(x):
    df.insert(loc=0, column='Creation_DT', value=str(pd.to_datetime('today')))
    df.insert(loc=1, column='Creation_By', value="Sean")
    df.to_parquet("/home/sample.parquet")
add_col(df)
```